Schema validation json
What is the best way to do schema validation of a complex nested json in pyspark in databricks. My current input is a dataframe with one of the columns as a json.
I am trying to use Jsonschema library to validate it using udf and it is making the code extremely slow.
Any help here would be appreciated

Jsonschema is written in Python thus could be slow. I recommend to use Pydantic v2 that is written in Rust. If you have JSON-schema in JSON format you could convert it to Pydantic model with datamodel-code-gen tool:
https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/integrations/datamodel_code_generator/#code-generation-with-datamodel-code-generator
This solution could be more efficient, but I will be gratefull if someone show me the native pyspark solution to validate complex JSON like could libraries which work on JSON-schema.
Several solutions but None are perfect. From the fastest with PySpark:

explode each nested column with arrays & structs and check them with Spark SQL - isn't sound good
write Scala UDF with Everit JSON library from Maven: https://semanticinsight.wordpress.com/2020/10/18/databricks-spark-json-validation-governance/ and play with run Scala in PySpark - needs effort but possible
Pydantic on the Rust + Python UDF - the simplest way

Apart from that i checked

https://pandera.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pyspark_sql.html - PySpark is a new API in Pandera and in the future could be nice, but now it cannot handle nested data. Only flat DF.
Fugue tool https://fugue-tutorials.readthedocs.io/ tries to convert your custom DF transformation from PySpark to Pandas vectorized UDF which is much faster that common Python UDF. Still nested data is a blocker.
I found great-expectation tool, but still I am checking this out

